# Calculate binance ATR in python with binance connector

Tags: python, math, algorithmic-trading, binance

I'm using the binance connector API in python (https://binance-connector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) and I want to build a function that computes the ATR of the previous candle (not the current one) based on a given length. I'm using the candlestick data format provided by the API: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#kline-candlestick-data. This is the code:

```py
def tr(prices: list[list], length: int) -> list[float]:
    prices = prices[len(prices)-length-1:]
    tr_list: list[float] = []

    for i in range(1, len(prices)):
        high = float(prices[i][2])
        low = float(prices[i][3])
        close = float(prices[i-1][4])

        current_true_range = max(
            (high - low),
            abs(high - close),
            abs(low - close),
        )

        tr_list.append(current_true_range)

    return tr_list

def atr(prices: list[list], length: int) -> float:
    tr_values = tr(prices, length)
    return sum(tr_values) / len(tr_values)
```

this is how I get the klines:

```py
self.binance_api_client.klines(symbol=self.trading_symbol, interval=self.klines_interval, limit=self.klines_limit_length)
```

I don't use the last kline because it's never complete yet, I only use the previous closed klines (that's why I use `[:-1]`):

```
atr = technical_indicators.atr(klines[:-1], 14)
```

However, I still don't get the right value and the error is significant, what am I doing wrong ? (self.klines_limit_length is, in this context, 200).

I've made sure that the interval is the same and I'm sure that I get the right data.

---

***UPDATE:***

When I call the supertrend function I always pass in the klines without the last candle (since it's not closed yet) so I don't have to think about not taking into consideration the values of the last candlestick when calculating the tr/atr. ***I now know that I am getting the right prices in the `tr` function***, the problem that I have now is that, for some reason, ***the supertrend is still wrong***.

This is all the code:

```py
def tr(prices: list[list], length: int) -> list[float]:
    prices = prices[-length:]
    tr_list: list[float] = []

    for i in range(1, len(prices)):
        high = float(prices[i][2])
        low = float(prices[i][3])
        close = float(prices[i-1][4])

        current_true_range = max(
            (high - low),
            abs(high - close),
            abs(low - close),
        )

        tr_list.append(current_true_range)

    return tr_list

def atr(prices: list[list], length: int) -> float:
    tr_values = tr(prices, length)
    return sum(tr_values) / len(tr_values)


def supertrend(prices: list[list], length: int, multiplier: float) -> float:
    high = float(prices[-1][2])
    low = float(prices[-1][3])
    atr_value = atr(prices, length)

    supertrend = (low + high) / 2 + multiplier * atr_value
    return supertrend
```

I already exclude the last price when calling the supertrend:

```py
supertrend = technical_indicators.supertrend(klines[:-1], 20, 2)
```

The klines have always at least 200 prices, so the length of 20 is not a problem.

Comment: You need Automatic Target Recognition of a candle?

Comment: @Stef by ATR I mean Average True Range at the last candle, not at the current one.

Comment: When you slice the **high** and **low**, in **supertrend** you’re getting the last one. Shouldn’t you get the before last?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi No, because when I call the supertrend function I give it as argument the klines without the last one. I'm essentially doing what you're saying before calling the function

Answer (score 3):

I think you are slicing wrongly, I don't have access to the binance api but can you change this line.

`prices[-length-1:-1]` instead of `prices[len(prices)-length-1:]`

That way you will get the latest prices at the end of the array instead.

If this doesn't work you need to check if the bars that you are getting are correct. Maybe you could paste the result of the most recent bars you have and I can work on it from there.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late comment. The prices that I get are correct. I don't need to exclude the last candlestick since I already do that when I call the supertrend function. I am now sure that the prices that I calculate in the true range function are correct and that I get the correct amount of prices, the problem is that the supertrend is somehow still wrong

Comment: Why don’t you get the prices raw and calculate it yourself? Is there a way to get the prices raw?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by getting the prices "raw" ? I get the actual prices without delay and try to calculate the supertrend value myself

Comment: Could you share the data you pull ?